# Why Adtree has more accuracy than C4.5

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree

I've been working on a data mining project lately, and it confuses me a lot that alternating decision tree seems to have more accuracy than WEKA built-in j48 algorithm. I don't have much idea about how these two algorithms are implemented, I hope someone can explain this from the  algorithm point of view. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have much idea about how these two algorithms are implemented

No one can explain to you why one can perform better than the other if you don't even understand the starting points. Learn about C4.5 and then learn about ADTrees.

Otherwise this would be an exercise in trying to teach you two algorithms in a single giant post - which is futile.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will do more research next time before asking question.